# As traffic block a website with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, sites

Hello everyone I found this code .htaccess to block a website, but do not understand why in the first line is [NC, OR] and the second link does not?
So okay if I want to block traffic 2 or more websites?

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} lsale02\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} esoqld.ru\.ru  <------- **does not have [NC,OR]**
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Read the manual? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html NC = Nocase, OR is or statement for condition followed by rule. So if you have multiple separate conditions u use [OR] if you have additional conditions you dont use [OR] wich defaults to AND

Comment: I do not understand what I want to do is block the traffic of those 2 web

What is the correct code?

Comment: Your question was why it has NC and OR, i explained why it is, your question wasnt: the code doesnt work..

Comment: then that code so right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deny access to more websites, add more like below. Small notice, every point needs to be escaped:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} lsale02\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} another\.ru [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} esoqld\.ru\.ru [NC]   # last one doesn't need OR because there will be no more conditions.
RewriteRule .* - [F]  # returns a 403 [F]orbidden
```